# Why is the JavaBean standard to is for booleans instead of get

Tags: java, javabeans

Why is the JavaBean standard set to use the prefix is- for a getter instead of get-?

It seems to be a really out place for a uniform naming convention, especially for only a single getter for a single type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reads better. Compare:

- Girl.getBeautiful()
- Girl.isBeautiful()

or even

- Coin.getGold()
- Coin.isGold()

Comment: `beer.isDrunk()` vs. `beer.getDrunk()`

Comment: Dude.isHigh() vs. Dude.getHigh()

Comment: Your example looks you're calling a static method from a class `Girl` or `Coin`.

Comment: That's fine as long as my point gets across. I don't necessarily suggest you try to compile my examples.

Answer (score 4):

You can have "get" on a boolean too, it's allowed. I think they did this for readability. you say

```
if (bean.isImmutable()) { // Better
```

rather than

```
if (bean.getImmutable()) { //Get what?
```

---

Also, if you use reflection on JavaBeans and you see a getter method starting with a "is", you can do a type check to see if the return type of this getter method is a boolean (because only boolean have the special case of "is" getter method).